# SQL Lite: I want to add +1 everytime a criteria is met

Tags: sql, sqlite

So i want to check if a criteria is met and then add +1 everytime.

i tried it like this

```
SELECT Track,
 CASE 
 WHEN Duration like '%05:%' then metrics_count + 1
 WHEN Danceable = 'not very danceable' then metrics_count + 1
 WHEN Energy = 'high energy' then metrics_count + 1
 WHEN Emotion = 'moody' THEN metrics_count + 1
 WHEN  "Key" = 'C#' THEN metrics_count + 1
End as metrics_count
FROM
 table
```

but i just get nulls or 1 so it doest add up it restarts everytime i think.

Comment: Please provide table structure, sample data and desired result [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks you need next

```
SELECT Track,
    (case when Duration like '%05:%' then 1 else 0 end) +
    (case when Danceable = 'not very danceable' then 1 else 0 end) +
    (case when Energy = 'high energy' then 1 else 0 end) +
    -- other cases
    (case when Emotion = 'moody' then 1 else 0 end) as metrics_count
FROM
 table
```

[SQLite online test](https://sqlize.online/sql/sqlite3/d913df7b2592ae79c5421b3fe015c936/)